# Software for orbital sketches

Tags: orbital-mechanics, software

I am looking for recommendations on software that can create orbit sketches such as the image below. Adding an informative sketch to an article can help readers better understand the idea.

I am familiar with Tikz but I did not manage to create too complex plots without getting lost in the code.

Open source is better but I don't mind paying a bit for a good solution. I will also apprentice a nice GUI :) Any suggestion?

Source: https://adcsforbeginners.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/a1.png

[image: adcsforbeginners.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/a1.png]

Comment: Yeah... SketchUp is terrible when it comes to drawing anything round or curved, and I'm not too fond of taking screenshots in Kerbal Space Program after preparing the set of orbits through hyperedit, then  maneuvers through PreciseNode.

Comment: Graphics like this you can do quite easily in any vector graphics program. Inkscape is one quite popular free software for that.

Comment: I use Mathematica, which is commercial (and probably too expensive), but wolfram.com (not Wolfram Alpha) allows you to access some Mathematica features for free online.

Comment: @barrycarter How much learning is required to make diagrams like this using Mathematica, starting from zero experience? What kind of syntax would be used? I'm intrigued.

Comment: @barrycarter Could you please provide an example script? I have access to Mathematica but I do not have to much experience with it.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect anyone to actually take me up on it :) I'd like to clean it up, but, in ugly form: go to https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/ look for any subdirectory with files like `image*` (STACK has the most, QUORA, REDDIT, MATHEMATICA also have a few), and then find the .m file referencing that image. Somewhere in all the clutter in the .m file are the graphics that draw the image. I do want to clean this up, but I thought it'd be good to at least give a sample. Feel free, as always, to contact me directly (contact info in profile)

Answer (score 3):

When just throwing something together, I use [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/).

2D and 3D diagrams can be constructed from mathematical primitives, both declaratively or through drawing.

There's a bit of everything in it. A computer algebra system, LaTeX, spreadsheets, scripting and so on. None of it works particularly *well*, but when you don't feel like making a custom graphic, you can make something reasonable in 15 minutes.

[image: geogebra version of diagram]

Comment: Seconding GeoGebra. It can be _very_ annoying to use at some times, but it can be used to solve Kepler's equations for some kind of nice [animations](https://imgur.com/a/pnDDTOC) I've used for a few answers here and there.